Powershell clock in top right corner
I want a clock in the top right corner of the terminal using powershell similar if not identical to the bash script provided below.
Bash snippet:
while true; do echo -ne "\e[s\e[0;$((COLUMNS-7))H\e[30;47m$(date +'%H:%M:%S')\e[0m\e[u"; sleep 1; done &

And i want something similar in PowerShell. I tried this:
Clear-Host

function Show-Clock {
    $width = [console]::WindowWidth
    $height = [console]::WindowHeight
    $x = $width - 8  # Width for "HH:MM:SS"
    $y = 0

    while ($true) {
        $time = (Get-Date).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
        [console]::SetCursorPosition($x, $y)
        Write-Host "$time" -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Black -NoNewline
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

Show-Clock

And it works but you cant use the terminal while its running which i want to.
Any help is appreciated!
Edit 1:
Now i used Start-Process -NoNewWindow in order to mimic the ampersands (&) functionality but that didnt work either:
Clear-Host

function Show-Clock {
    $width = [console]::WindowWidth
    $height = [console]::WindowHeight

    $clockPositionX = $width - 8  # Width for "HH:MM:SS"
    $clockPositionY = 0

    while ($true) {
        $time = (Get-Date).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
        [console]::SetCursorPosition($clockPositionX, $clockPositionY)
        Write-Host "$time" -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Black -NoNewline
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command 'Show-Clock'" -NoNewWindow


This question is similar to: Powershell equivalent of bash ampersand (&) for forking/running background processes. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Cpt.Whale: From a parallel runspace / thread job you can manipulate the caller's console (terminal), via the .NET [Console] class, as my answer shows.

@mklement0 awesome! I see I was configuring my runspace incorrectly compared to what the Threadjob module does. And of course forgot the old ISE console doesn't behave the same way


While you could make your Start-Process -NoNewWindow approach work if you added saving and restoring the current cursor location, it has two downsides (on Windows; doesn't affect Unix-like platforms):

Pressing Ctrl+C in the session doesn't just abort any foreground operation, but also the time-displaying process.

Conversely, when you exit the session, the time-displaying process lingers and keeps the console window open, giving the impression of a hang; pressing Ctrl+C terminates that process too and closes the window.


The best solution is to use a thread (parallel PowerShell runspace) in which to run the time-displaying code, which is most easily achieved with the Start-ThreadJob cmdlet.[1]

This cmdlet comes with PowerShell (Core) 7.

In Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1) it can be installed on demand, using, e.g., Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser


The following, which is a translation of your bash command,[2] works in both PowerShell editions, in both regular console windows and in Windows Terminal, and also on Unix-like platforms (assuming that the terminal of interest supports saving and restoring the cursor position via ANSI escape sequences):[3]
# See below for an alternative that doesn't require Start-ThreadJob.
$null = Start-ThreadJob { 
  $esc = [char] 0x1B
  while ($true) {
    [Console]::Write((
      '{0}[s{0}[0;{1}H{0}[30;47m{2}{0}[m{0}[u' -f 
        $esc, 
        ([Console]::WindowWidth - 7), 
        [datetime]::Now.ToString('HH:mm:ss')
    ))
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
  }
}

Note:

While PowerShell jobs, unlike Bash jobs, do not print their output directly to the console (and instead require on-demand retrieval of output via Receive-Job, the [Console] .NET class provides direct access to the caller's console (terminal).


On Windows PowerShell, if you cannot / don't want to install the module that contains Start-ThreadJob, you can use the PowerShell SDK directly, as follows:
$scriptBlock = { 
  $esc = [char] 0x1B
  while ($true) {
    [Console]::Write((
      '{0}[s{0}[0;{1}H{0}[30;47m{2}{0}[m{0}[u' -f 
        $esc, 
        ([Console]::WindowWidth - 7), 
        [datetime]::Now.ToString('HH:mm:ss')
    ))
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
  }
}

$null = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($scriptBlock).BeginInvoke()


[1] Note that PowerShell's regular background jobs, which are created with Start-Job, are not an option in this case, because they create a child process rather than a thread, and that child process isn't connected to the caller's console.
For a juxtaposition of background jobs (Start-Job) and the generally preferable thread jobs (Start-ThreadJob), see this answer.
[2] It's tempting to try to run your original Bash command directly from PowerShell, via bash -c '...', but that doesn't actually work: the time prints in the wrong place (at the current prompt on Unix-like platforms) or not visibly at all (when calling bash.exe from outside WSL on Windows).
[3] On macOS, the built-in Terminal.app application does not support the cursor-location saving/restoring ANSI esscape sequences, but popular third-party alternative iTerm.app does. My guess is that most Linux terminals do have the necessary support.
